# BigQuery Invalid dataset ID

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I used to query in UI
This time, I'm in cloud shell, and try to access my dataset and table through python

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'mytest-0001:reports_test'
table_id = 'test_data'
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
print('Dataset ID: '.format(dataset_id))
print('Description: '.format(dataset.description))
print(table.schema)
print(table.description)
print(table.num_rows)
```

I got some the error below...

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcd-my-reporting/datasets/mytest-0001:reports_test: Invalid dataset ID "mytest-0001:reports_test". Dataset IDs must be al
>   phanumeric (plus underscores, dashes, and colons) and must be at most 1024 characters long.

With some reason I can't modified the dataset id, Any idea to fixed this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to modify `dataset id`, just specify the `dataset id` without `project id`. If you want to specify project for any reason, you must to do it when define `client` as explained in [this document](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#projects).

The code will be:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project='mytest-0001')
dataset_id = 'reports_test'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your project name is `mytest-0001`, you should set the dataset ID to `'reports_test'`. It looks like you are including the project name in the dataset ID, which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the project_id from dataset_id and similar with table_id just write the name of dataset and table and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataset` and `table` name like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client()
tableRef = bigqueryClient.dataset(datasetName).table(tableName)
```